# How to register mutli LLVM Pass in one file?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I register the function Pass using registerPipelineParsingCallback following the new Pass Manager requirements.

However, I found that I can only register single functionPass or ModulePass. How can I register both of them in one file?

my register code is

```
extern "C" ::llvm::PassPluginLibraryInfo LLVM_ATTRIBUTE_WEAK
llvmGetPassPluginInfo() {
    return {
            LLVM_PLUGIN_API_VERSION, "HelloNewPMPass", "v0.1",
            [](PassBuilder &PB) {
                PB.registerPipelineParsingCallback(
                        [](StringRef PassName, FunctionPassManager &FPM,...) {
                            if (PassName == "fiber") {
                                FPM.addPass(HelloNewPMPass());
                                return true;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                );
            }
    };
}
```

I have both function Pass and Module pass in one file like below:

```
namespace {
    struct HelloNewPMPass : public PassInfoMixin<HelloNewPMPass> {
        PreservedAnalyses run(Function &F, FunctionAnalysisManager &FAM) {
            PreservedAnalyses pa = PreservedAnalyses::all();
            return pa;
        }
    };
    struct SecondPass: public PassInfoMixin<StringEncryptionPass> {
      PreservedAnalyses run(Module &M, ModuleAnalysisManager &MAM) {
        errs() << M.getName() << "\n";
        PreservedAnalyses pa = PreservedAnalyses::all();
        return pa;
      }
    };
}
```

Diving into the interface of registerPipelineParsingCallback, I found that the lamda function's parameter which registerPipelineParsingCallback need could be used either `FunctionPassManager` or `ModulePassManager`.

I wonder how can I register Module&Function PassManager at the same time.
Using the lambda function like below doesn't work

```
PB.registerPipelineParsingCallback(
                        [](StringRef PassName, FunctionPassManager &FPM, ModulePassManager &MPM) {
...
                            return false;
                        }
                );
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use PB.registerPipelineParsingCallback twice.
just like:

```
    return {LLVM_PLUGIN_API_VERSION, "HelloNewPMPass", "v0.1",
        [](PassBuilder &PB) {
            PB.registerPipelineParsingCallback([](StringRef PassName, FunctionPassManager &FPM,...){
                if(PassName = "hellonewpmpass"){FPM.addPass(HelloNewPMPass());return true;}
                return false;
            });
            PB.registerPipelineParsingCallback([](StringRef PassName, ModulePassManager &MPM,...){
                if(PassName = "secondpass"){MPM.addPass(SecondPass());return true;}
                return false;
            });
        }
    };
```

the first registerPipelineParsingCallback receive FunctionPassManager, the second receive ModulePassManager